# Solving for variable via exponents with even roots (positive/negative answer)

Tags: linear-algebra

Looking for some confirmation on what appears to be true but still makes me wonder if I'm overly inductive.

Here's the scene:

$ x^2 = 9 $ means that $ x = \pm 3$ (because we are applying an even root).

$ x^3 = 27 $ means that $ x = 3$ (because we are applying an odd root).

To take it up a notch with fractional exponents:

$ x^{2/3} = 9 $  requires exponents on both sides to isolate $x$:

$ (x^{ 2/3})^{3/2} = \pm 9^{3/2} $  (Since I am applying an even root, I must use $\pm$ to get both possibilities.)

*However*: If I simply the $9$ to $3^2$, I get this:

$ x = \pm 9^{3/2} = \pm (3^2)^{3/2}  = \pm 3^{6/2} = \pm 3^{3/1} $

Since the root reduces down to $1$ (an odd number), I wasn't sure if I still apply the $\pm$ as per the *original* root or if it should reflect any future simplifications.

In other words, would the answer above be merely $x = 27$ or $x = \pm 27$?

My basic testing with Wolfram Alpha suggested that the original $\pm$ still applies, regardless of any future simplifications.  And, of course, $x = -27$ does work in the original equation, which proves this particular instance!

But I wanted to make sure I understood what was happening on a more comprehensive level before moving on in my studies.

Thanks!

Comment: For most text if $r\not \in \mathbb Z$ and $b < 0 $then $b^r$ is not defined at all.  You can't say $x^{\frac 23} = 9$ assumes $x > 0$ and $x = 27$ because $(-27)^{\frac 23}$ is not defined.  .... If instead the question was $(x^2)^{\frac 13} = 9$ that is an *entirely* different question.  $(x^2)^{\frac 13} \ne x^{\frac 23}$ unless $x > 0$.

Comment: @fleablood Is there somewhere I could read more about how  $(x^2)^{1/3} \ne x^{2/3}$ unless x > 0?  I always thought that the fractional exponent merely meant doing the exponent and root both (in either order), which seems like it would work (with -27 cube-rooted to -3 then squared to 9 or -27 squared to 729 and then cube-rooted to 9, both seeming to work great).

Comment: Read any text book.  Basically, when it comes to defining exponents it won't make sense to define on negative bases.  if $b< 0$ then $b^{\frac 12}$ isn't defined. and $b^{\frac 35} = b^{\frac 6{10}}$ is not well defined and if $x \not \in \mathbb Q$ then $b^x$ doesn't mean anything. And $\log_b M$ is badly defined for $b < 0$.  ....So we just don't do it.... sometimes.  Some texts do.

Comment: Also think about it.  If $x$ is irrational, how do you define $b^x$?

Comment: Also bear in mind.  $x = \pm 3$ does not mean there is a special number called $\pm 3$ and $x$ is equal to it.  $x =\pm 3$ means that there are two possible solutions to $x$; $x =3$ is one possible solution and $x=-3$ is the other.  So if you have $x^{\frac 23} =9$ then that is the question.  What values of numbers can $x$ be so that $x^{\frac 23}=9$.  That depeends on how $x^{\frac 23}$ is defined.  If the text does it as yours does $x^{\frac 23}=9$ means $x^{\frac 13}=\pm 3$ and $x =\pm 27$ of $x^2 = 9^3=3^6$ and $x =\pm 3^3=\pm 27$.  *If* that is how it is defined.  Check *your* text.

Comment: Using your definition you wrote "$x = \pm 9^{3/2} = \pm (3^2)^{3/2}  = \pm 3^{6/2} = \pm 3^{3/1}$"  Thatn doesn't work.  What you are trying to do is $x=9^{\frac 32}$ (no reason to and $\pm$, $x^{23}\ne -9$.  You were *TOLD* it is was $+9$.  So $x=9^{\frac 32} = (3^2)^{\frac 32}= [(3^2)^{\frac 12}]^3= [\pm 3]^3 = \pm 27$.  The $\pm$ comes *AFTER* you take the square root; not before..... but I still think you shouldn't define $x^{r}$ for $r\not \in \mathbb Z$ and $x < 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Not that $x^{\frac 1n}$ is the *PRINCIPAL* and *positive* root of $x$.

So you don't solve $x^2 = 36$ by taking the $\frac 12$ exponent.

$(x^2)^{\frac {1}2} = (36)^{\frac 12}$ is true but

$x = 6$ is not. The thing is $(x^2)^{\frac 12} \ne x$.  And the $\frac 12$ power is the *positive* rot the negative root is not acheived.

Instead $(x^2)^{\frac 12} = |x|$ and we get

$x^2 = 36$ so

$(x^2)^{\frac 12} = 36^{\frac 12}$

$|x| = 6$

$x = 6$ or $x = -6$.  But most of us just skip the absolute value step in our head and do

$x^2 = 36$ so we have rule that $x = \pm 36^{\frac 12} = \pm 6$.

....

So for $x^{\frac 23} = 9$ we can do

$(x^2)^\frac 13 = 9$

$x^2 = 9^3$

$x = \pm 3^3 = \pm 27$.

Or we can do

$x^{\frac 23} = 9$

$(x^{\frac 13})^2 = 9 = 3^2$

So

$|x^{\frac 13}| = 3$

$x^{\frac 13} = \pm 3$

$x = (\pm 3)^3 = \pm 27$.

......

But as I mentioned in the comments; for many texts   $b^r; r \not \in \mathbb Z$ are only defined if $b \ge 0$.  Your texts may or may not follow this.